# javascript show hidden element when input is filled

Tags: javascript, show-hide

hey i would like to show an table when user fills an input.

What I have is:

in `<head>` section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//hide initially    
$("table#mytable").hide();

// show function
function showit() {
$("table#mytable").show();
}
</script>
```

and the table:

```
<table id="mytable"><tr><td>FOO</td><td>BAR</td></tr></table>
```

and a form below(maybe it is important) the table:

```
<form action="foobar.php">
<input name="example" onselect="showit()" />
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

I think onselect isn't perfect but it should do the thing in my case.

The code above doesn't hide the table at all. I don't know what I did wrong. Hope some1 can find a mistake - thank you.

EDIT

here is the solution:

`head`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

and in every element to hide just add `style="display: none;"` and edit input - add `onkeyup="show('id')` where id is id of element to hide e.g. `#mytable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is because you are calling the javascript before the table element is rendered. There are three ways of doing this:

```
// Use CSS (best):
<table style="display:none;" id="mytable">...</table>
```

or

```
// Using DOM Load event (wait for all of the elements to render) (second best)
$(function() { $("table#mytable").hide(); });
```

or

```
// Put your javascript at the bottom of the page instead of the head. (not preferred)
```

Comment: Why the _not preferred_ for the scripts at the bottom of the page? [Best Practices for Speeding up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)

Comment: tried 1 and 2 - didn' work somehow. i don't know why. with `display:none` I could not show it but it was hidden properly

Comment: I used 1. - and found another way to change it - i guess hide() and show didnt work in my case - check edit

Comment: @Andreas why wait for the javascript to run before you hide your element? The best practice is to deal with style using CSS and control with Javascript. It is true that javascript at the bottom is a best practice for optimal rendering, but using CSS in this particular case is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use onkeyup and document ready might help

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#mytable").hide();
   $("#example").keyup(function (e) { 
$("#mytable").show();
}) 
});​
```

jfidle http://jsfiddle.net/dznej/

Comment: i have copied exactly yout jsfidle and checked on opera and ff - didn't work i don't know why - can it be caused by my server settings? js is client-side language but maybe sth is wrong there

Answer (score 0):

Check out the fiddle I've created for you - http://jsfiddle.net/ggJSg/

Basically there are two problems:

- You need to call `$("#mytable").hide();` only when DOM is ready
- Use proper event (like focus in my example) to trigger table display

Comment: I thought of focus too but it does not seem to be what the OP is asking for. The table should be shown when "user fills an input". I.e. when characters are entered in the textbox.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function to execute the code when the DOM has finished loading. Then you should use the [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function to display it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  // Hide initially    
  $('#mytable').hide();

  // When something changes in the input named `example` then show the table.
  $("[name='example']").change(function() {
    $('#mytable').show();
  });
});
```