# How to not add delete button when you input blank?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build to-do app and when I add something without typing anything (blank) it still comes with a delete button. I've set it as if you don't type anything in input, then the alert will show as "Please add a task." Here's what I did so far.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const taskForm = document.querySelector('#task-form');
  const taskInput = document.querySelector('#task-input');
  const taskList = document.querySelector('#task-list');

  taskForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const task = taskInput.value;
    addTask(task);
    taskInput.value = '';

    if (!task) {
      alert('Please add the task.');
      return;
    }
  });

  // Add button
  const addTask = (task) => {
    const divItem = document.createElement('div');
    const showItem = taskList.appendChild(divItem);
    showItem.innerHTML = task;

    // Delete button
    const buttonDelete = document.createElement('button');
    buttonDelete.innerHTML = 'Delete';
    divItem.appendChild(buttonDelete);

    buttonDelete.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      deleteTask(buttonDelete);
    });
  };

  const deleteTask = (buttonDelete) => {
    const selectTask = buttonDelete.closest('div');
    taskList.removeChild(selectTask);
  };
});
```

```html
<form id="task-form">
  <input id="task-input" type="text" placeholder="What's your plans?" />
  <input id="task-submit" type="submit" value="Push" />
</form>

<div>
  <h1>Tasks</h1>
  <div id="task-list"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like you just need to make the `addTask` function call _after_ the `if` statement

Comment: You have code that adds the delete button. If you don't want that to run, remove it....?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript show hidden element when input is filled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857801/javascript-show-hidden-element-when-input-is-filled) (the plain JavaScript equivalent of jQuery's `.hide()` is `element.hidden = true;`. `.show()` is `element.hidden = false;`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if taskInput.value is blank and then return BEFORE you call the addTask method.

```
    const task = taskInput.value;

    if (!task) {
      alert('Please add the task.');
      return;
    }

    addTask(task);
    taskInput.value = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if there is no value before adding the task (and not after)

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const taskForm = document.querySelector('#task-form');
  const taskInput = document.querySelector('#task-input');
  const taskList = document.querySelector('#task-list');

  taskForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const task = taskInput.value;

    if (!task) {
      alert('Please add the task.');
      return;
    }

    addTask(task);
    taskInput.value = '';
  });

  // Add button
  const addTask = (task) => {
    const divItem = document.createElement('div');
    const showItem = taskList.appendChild(divItem);
    showItem.innerHTML = task;

    // Delete button
    const buttonDelete = document.createElement('button');
    buttonDelete.innerHTML = 'Delete';
    divItem.appendChild(buttonDelete);

    buttonDelete.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      deleteTask(buttonDelete);
    });
  };

  const deleteTask = (buttonDelete) => {
    const selectTask = buttonDelete.closest('div');
    taskList.removeChild(selectTask);
  };
});
```

```html
<form id="task-form">
  <input id="task-input" type="text" placeholder="What's your plans?" />
  <input id="task-submit" type="submit" value="Push" />
</form>

<div>
  <h1>Tasks</h1>
  <div id="task-list"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const taskForm = document.querySelector('#task-form');
  const taskInput = document.querySelector('#task-input');
  const taskList = document.querySelector('#task-list');

  taskForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const task = taskInput.value;
    addTask(task);
    taskInput.value = '';
  });

  // Add button
  const addTask = (task) => {

    if (!task || task == "" || task == undefine) {
      alert('Please add the task.');
      return;
    }else{

    const divItem = document.createElement('div');
    const showItem = taskList.appendChild(divItem);
    showItem.innerHTML = task;

    // Delete button
    const buttonDelete = document.createElement('button');
    buttonDelete.innerHTML = 'Delete';
    divItem.appendChild(buttonDelete);

    buttonDelete.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      deleteTask(buttonDelete);
    });
   }
  };

  const deleteTask = (buttonDelete) => {
    const selectTask = buttonDelete.closest('div');
    taskList.removeChild(selectTask);
  };
});
```